# Expected DoFn to be FunctionSpec with URN beam:dofn:javasdk:0.1, but URN was

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

trying to submit job to dataflow via java -jar target/assembly.jar but failing with error below, but with direct runner it's working fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected DoFn to be FunctionSpec with URN beam:dofn:javasdk:0.1, but URN was
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:477)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.doFnWithExecutionInformationFromProto(ParDoTranslation.java:697)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getSchemaInformation(ParDoTranslation.java:389)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getSchemaInformation(ParDoTranslation.java:374)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$11.translateTyped(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:1158)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$11.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:1148)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$11.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:1144)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.visitPrimitiveTransform(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:484)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:664)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:251)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:463)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:423)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:182)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:910)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:195)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
    at com.Pipeline.main(Pipeline.java:74)
```

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pipeline</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <beam.version>2.24.0</beam.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.Pipeline</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>format</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocExecutable>/usr/local/bin/protoc</protocExecutable>
                    <protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/external/</protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/protobuf/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>url</url>
                    <user>user</user>
                    <password>a</password>
                    <placeholders>
                    <socketFactory>com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory</socketFactory>
                    </placeholders>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}-assembly</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.Pipeline</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.30.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev8-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>```
````

Comment: Have you tried to reach out Google support, composing request via [Public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) as it might increase a chance to debug stack trace by product developers?

Comment: Yes, I have already done that too.

Comment: Did you try to launch the job via Maven, more reference [here](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/#run-wordcount-using-maven)? Was it resulted with the same error?

Comment: Yes, with maven it works fine

Comment: I suppose this issue occurs because of missing dependencies in the generated jar, can you try to revise the `pom.xml` and re-compile jar file then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue can happen when the generated jar doesn't include some service implementations in META-INFO/services. Please try the following `maven-shade-plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin` for packaging.

I found the plugin configuration in pom.xml generated from [Beam Quickstart](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/#get-the-wordcount-code) .

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```