# Write To Kafka using Apache Beam (GCP Dataflow)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to send data to a Kafka topic in Python using `WriteToKafka` via Apache Beam using Dataflow as a runner.

By running the following script:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
        (p
        | beam.Impulse()
        | beam.Map(lambda input: (1, input))
        | WriteToKafka(
                    producer_config={
                        'bootstrap.servers': 'ip:9092,',
                    },
                    topic='testclient',
                    key_serializer='org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer',
                    value_serializer='org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer',
                )
         )
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denes/data-science/try_write_to_kafka.py", line 75, in <module>
    run_pipeline(beam_options)
  File "/home/denes/data-science/try_write_to_kafka.py", line 38, in run_pipeline
    (p
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 582, in __exit__
    self.result = self.run()
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 529, in run
    return Pipeline.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 904, in from_runner_api
    p.transforms_stack = [context.transforms.get_by_id(root_transform_id)]
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 115, in get_by_id
    self._id_to_obj[id] = self._obj_type.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1259, in from_runner_api
    part = context.transforms.get_by_id(transform_id)
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 115, in get_by_id
    self._id_to_obj[id] = self._obj_type.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1259, in from_runner_api
    part = context.transforms.get_by_id(transform_id)
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 115, in get_by_id
    self._id_to_obj[id] = self._obj_type.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1259, in from_runner_api
    part = context.transforms.get_by_id(transform_id)
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 115, in get_by_id
    self._id_to_obj[id] = self._obj_type.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1259, in from_runner_api
    part = context.transforms.get_by_id(transform_id)
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/pipeline_context.py", line 115, in get_by_id
    self._id_to_obj[id] = self._obj_type.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 1236, in from_runner_api
    transform = ptransform.PTransform.from_runner_api(proto, context)
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 700, in from_runner_api
    return constructor(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1419, in from_runner_api_parameter
    DoFnInfo.from_runner_api(
  File "/home/denes/data-science/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1493, in from_runner_api
    raise ValueError('Unexpected DoFn type: %s' % spec.urn)
ValueError: Unexpected DoFn type: beam:dofn:javasdk:0.1
```

Note that I have installed the latest apache-beam version (supported by [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python)) via `pip install 'apache-beam[gcp]'`.

- apache-beam==2.27.0
- google-cloud-core==1.5.0

If I am not wrong, the problem is with the serialization methods. I have tried all sorts of combinations that I have found on [this](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/) page.

What do I miss, what should I do differently?

Comment: Have you tested your code without setting the `key_serializer` and `value_serializer` ? According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/apache_beam.io.external.kafka.html), it would go to the default `org.apache.kafka.common. serialization.ByteArraySerializer` .and `org.apache.kafka.common. serialization.ByteArraySerializer`.

Comment: Also, have found an example in ApacheBeam's GitHub which shows multiple usages of  `WriteToKafka` method, [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c758a0d68d881df40e80f61691315b6f0222008f/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/portability/flink_runner_test.py#L267). Did this information help you?

Comment: Hi @AlexandreMoraes, thank you for replying. I have found the page that you mentioned, in fact I was copying the logic of `key_serializer` and `value_serializer` from that very page.

As for your other suggestion, I have of course tried it and if I run without specifying the serializers then I get this error:
`RuntimeError: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarLongCoder cannot be cast to class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder (org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarLongCoder and org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: I understand. I need to confirm, have you imported all the necessary libraries for your code ? Such as the ones shown on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c758a0d68d881df40e80f61691315b6f0222008f/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/portability/flink_runner_test.py#L267).

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Your error can be related to your Python dependencies, such as described in this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388265/expected-dofn-to-be-functionspec-with-urn-beamdofnjavasdk0-1-but-urn-was). Could you check your dependencies such as described in the Apache Beam [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use explicit type conversion for both key and value.

```
    | 'Convert dict to byte string' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (b'', json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8')))
      .with_output_types(typing.Tuple[bytes, bytes])
    | "Write to Kafka topic" >> WriteToKafka(
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': consumer_servers},
        topic='testclient')
      )
```